How can i drill down in a Bugsnag error and get the StackTrace with Powershell?
I am using the following api call to get errors :
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.bugsnag.com/projects/<project_id>/errors" -Headers    $headers -Method Get 

But this does not give the stack Trace.
How can i get the stack trace from this ?
I have tried drilling down to the events url that is returned

I had a similar issue, but so long as your URL matches exactly what the app URL shows, the stacktrace exists in the events. I had mixed up events and errors too, leading me to think I couldn't see the stack traces.
